# AntLR4 in Go: Invalid type assertion: listener

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

I generated Parser for the Go Language from Antlr4 grammar.

Grammar is here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/solidity/Solidity.g4

I generate parser as follows:
    java -jar $PWD/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Go -o parser syntax/Solidity.g4

The generated `solidity_parser.go` file has the following error whereever `listener.(SolidityListener)` shows up:

Invalid type assertion: listener.(SolidityListener) (non-interface type antlr.ParseTreeListener on left)

Code snippet:

`func (s *SourceUnitContext) EnterRule(listener antlr.ParseTreeListener) {
    if listenerT, ok := listener.(SolidityListener); ok { // <-- here is the error
        listenerT.EnterSourceUnit(s)
    }
}`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: can not find declaration to go]

I met the same problem. The reason is go cannot find the interface definition, just run `go get github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr` would solve the problem.